# How can I remove commands from the menu after "Ok, Glass"

Tags: android, google-glass

I am trying to demo some glassware and would like to remove all the baked-in commands like 'Google', 'Take picture', 'Show viewfinder' and so forth.  Is there a simple way to do that?

So far, I have been able to get rid of a few of them (like  'Send Message' and 'Call') following [this tutorial for XE12](http://tech.pristine.io/removing-items-from-the-ok-glass-menu/) after modifying a few things for XE21 (mentioned in the comments below the article).  However, the majority of the items are not put in the menu the same way and I haven't been able to find out where they are in the disassembled GlassHome APK.

Am I going about this the entirely wrong way?  Is there a simple way to uninstall or clear those menu items out?  (Hopefully with some adb commands)

Answer (score 0):

Try the same way that you add commands, i.e. try removing the apps with voice triggers that add to the menu.

Comment: I don't see anything with a "trigger command".  And no activity/service that looks like the built in apps inside the manifest.